# Transistioning from Excel to Access - challenges in assigning/determining a Primary Key

Tags: excel, ms-access

I am currently working on attempting to transition a large database of testing records from Excel to Access to allow for better relational analysis between different groups; however, with how our team completes tests the same tests are repeated on a cycle making it difficult to capture a unique ID -

I have considered assigning one for each test but then realized the ID would still repeat when the test is ran again. I have considered using the timeframe of the review but that would also be repeated unless I build a separate table for each individual test. I have considered using the issue number that would be assigned to items requiring action, but this would not apply to all rows therefore access would not allow it.

Within our current database we capture test name, type, timeframe reviewed, start and end dates, result types, descriptions and root cause, and issue identifiers if remediation is required.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how I might transition this data into Access without losing the Primary Key feature on certain tables?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest creating a master table to identify your 'test types' (the things that can be run multiple times). You populate this table with the unique entries in the test name column in your Excel data. This column in your Excel data then becomes a 'foreign key' pointing to your master 'test types' table.

Ideally I would recommend using an autonumber as the primary key in the master table and then replacing the test name column in your Excel data with the numeric values generated when you populate the 'test types' table.

You would then import your Excel data into a table that is recording 'Test Run Instances'. Again I would set an autonumber field as the primary key on this table. Other columns in your Excel data that contain repeating data would make candidates for other 'master' tables (e.g. you talk about 'result types' - is there a set list of these that could be moved out to a master table?).